# How do you stay in the right git branch?

Tags: git

I use git but I am constantly finding myself in the wrong branch and then when I commit I realize I have done a ton of work in the wrong place.

How do you avoid doing this? Is it just something that comes with time? Or is there some trick you have to avoid this?

Comment: not an answer. but i usually use stash if i've not yet commited, and / or cherry pick the commit over and reset the other branch back one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git branch in prompt like [this](https://coderwall.com/p/fasnya/add-git-branch-name-to-bash-prompt) but this could be only applied, when you are using bash, or you can use [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with git plugin.

Another option could be a pre-commit hook, which runs only once: you can find here an [example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-commit.sample). This could warn you about the target branch. Pre-commit hooks can also protect the master/production branch, no push without pull-request. With [Yelp's framework](http://pre-commit.com/), you have more options.

Answer (score 0):

i dont use this (see my comment) but i know these things exist:
https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt

i.e: a bash prompt which changes as you change branches to keep you aware of which branch you're on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thats why i put the i.e. There's many other alternatives, and the thrust of it is: use a program, such as that linked to.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, but it works very well. Post-its! Yes, add a post-it somewhere you'll glance over while coding. "Have you checked your git branch?" A more technical solution would be to make it show when opening a terminal or your IDE, maybe change the 'default' file to something that asked you to check. Or use a post-it program. Or, if you're going for a more fun solution, add a speech synthesis program to your login script that says that. There are some code editors/IDE's that integrate with git and show the branch in a status bar.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single answer for this other than personal practise. You should make it part of your day to review the previous day's commits and branches in your favourite GIT browser.

As long as you don't stage the files you can change or create a new branch from your working copy.

Normally your IDE will integrate with GIT and show the branch you are on. My primary IDEs are PHP Storm and Visual Studio but this functionality is available in Netbeans and Sublime. In Visual Studio on the bottom right there is a branch indicator.

[image: VS2015 GIT Branch]

PHP Storm has a similar thing in the same location.

[image: PHP Storm GIT Branch]